# Angular2 + Ag-grid - Is it possible to move up/down a row with a button?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a problem with my ag-grid array, I have this array :

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
        <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" class="ag-fresh"
                         [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                         [rowData]="rowData"
                         [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                         enableColResize
                         rowSelection="multiple"
                         (columnResized)="onColumnEvent($event)"
                         (columnPinnedCountChanged)="onColumnEvent($event)">
        </ag-grid-angular>
    </div>
```

And I have two buttons :

```
<div class="bouton" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Déplacer instruction vers le haut">
    <button (click)="moveUp()">
        <img src="/src/images/flechehaut.png" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
            </button>
</div>
<div class="bouton" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Déplacer instruction vers le bas">
    <button (click)="moveDown()">
        <img src="/src/images/flechebas.png" style="width:60px;height:60px;" />
    </button>
</div>
```

And I was wondering if it was possible to move up an entire row with my *move up* button and to move down a row with my *move down* button.
I looked on the [ag-grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-features/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0) but found nothing about this possibility.

Is it at least possible ? And if it is, how should I look into this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can think of two possibilities:

1. Rearrange the rowData and reload it in the grid

   - This may get costly depending on how many rows you have
   - I sure hope you have sorting disabled on all your columns, otherwise your `moveUp` and `moveDown` functions would be useless
2. Create a column that has the order of the items in ascending order then your `moveUp`/`moveDown` functions would just update this number to one more or less, then you resort the grid based on those new values.

   - This would keep the order of the rowData the same as when it was initially sent to the grid, but DISPLAY it in a particular order.
   - I think it might be possible to hide this extra column and still have it be sorted on said column.

Comment: So I created a column _step_ where the number increase each time I add a row; but now, how can I modify this value with a button ?
I actually could modify it if I add `editable: true` to my `gridOptions.columnDefs` but this is not what I want to do.