# Ag-Grid How can move rows (In Angular7 code) by using buttons for Up, Dow, Top and Bottom

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using Ag-Grid community version for Angular and create a UI with grid where user is able to move rows in grid by using Drag and Drop functionality (Managed Way). User is not comfortable with drag and drop feature by Ag-Grid.

Now I have to provide 4 Buttons on UI (UP, DOWN, TOP and BOTTOM) to move rows respectively. I am not able to find any property/method in documentation to perform such functionality. Can I get any help in this regard.

I got similar question on [Angular2 + Ag-grid - Is it possible to move up/down a row with a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43657659/angular2-ag-grid-is-it-possible-to-move-up-down-a-row-with-a-button)
But I don't think answer is appropriate in term of functionality.

I have already tried drag and drop but grid is not making it good experience to user.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that you linked to hints at usable solution.
Basically, you first need a way to control the order in which rows are displayed.
I suggest that you add a numeric 'rowIndex' property to your data object, and put that in a hidden column. Then sort the grid on this hidden column.

Have your up and down buttons call methods that re-calculate the rowIndex values on the rows.

And of course, you'd have to disable sorting in the grid if you want to maintain this order.

Another option, instead of maintaining the rowIndex on the data, is to present an array of data to the grid, and leave the grid unsorted. The grid *should* display the data in the order that it exists in the array. To move a row, create a new array with the row moved to the desired position.